# Find a commutable matrices of an upper triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have an upper triangular matrix A=（aij）n*n   i<=n,j<=n;

if i>=j, aij=1;

else  aij=0;

how to find a matrix B，st. AB=BA?

Answer (score 0):

Take a polynomial of any degree, for example $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ and evaluate your matrix as
$$p(A)=a_01\!\!1+a_1A+a_2A^2,$$
then these are many which you want, that is, $B=p(A)$ is going to commute with $A$.

**Adendum:**

What I saw in $3\times3$ matrices is things like this
$$A-1\!\!1=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]-
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&1\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{array}\right],$$
$$(A-1\!\!1)^2=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right],$$
but also $(A-1\!\!1)^3=0$.

Since $A-1\!\!1$ and $(A-1\!\!1)^2$ commutes with $A$ they are in your $$Z(A)=\{B\ :\mbox{$B=p(A)$ for some polynomial $p$}\}.$$

It seems then, that any polynomial in $A$ can be written
$$p(A)=a_2(A-1\!\!1)^2+a_1(A-1\!\!1)+a_01\!\!1,$$
settling that $\dim Z(A)=3$, in $\dim=9$ of the vector space of matrices $3\times 3$.

From here, to say something for $n\times n$ with $n\ge 4$, is at reach.

Comment: let Z(B) as the consist of all the matrix B.What is the basis of space z(B) and dimZ(B)?

Comment: well, it is an interesting subsequent question, I was making some computations and I saw something... but, what have  you tried about?

Comment: I started from 3*3 matrixes and did some induction. Maybe those upper triangular matrixes whose diagonal lines have the same elements are going to commute with A.But it is hard to prove that?

Comment: Observe
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}a&b&c\\0&a&b\\0&0&a\end{array}\right]=
a\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]
+b\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]
+c\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$